# jQuery use closures in callback function to manipulate $getJSON data

Tags: jquery, callback, closures

This is really getting me:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   (function(x) {     //use a closure to hold the "i" value
       request(arg[x], function(n) {
          //do something with the data returned from $getJSON
          console.log(n);
       });
   })(i)  //is this syntax correct?
}

function request(argX, callback) {    //is this syntax correct?
     $getJSON(parameter) { 
         //get request result
         ... 
     }
     callback(); //after request() function is completed, trigger the callback function
                 //is this syntax right? 

}
```

The reason I am using the callback function is because I want to manipulating the result from getJSON, so I need to wait the request function to complete.

I also need to bound the callback function with the loop index "i" value.

I have played the syntax for quite a while, but how come nothing was returned from the console log? It seems the callback function was never executed or executed before $getJSON was completed.

I need expert's help!

Comment: "It seems the callback function was never executed or executed before $getJSON was completed." --- correct. Because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous

Comment: request(arg[x], function(n) { is missing a closing bracket ')' no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getJSON` call is asynchronous, so you would be calling the `callback` function before the response has arrived.

Also you have a code bloack after the call to `getJSON`. The code in that won't get called after the result has arrived either, it's just a separate block that runs after the call, and also before the result arrives.

Put the callback function as a parameter in the call to `getJSON`:

```
function request(argX, callback) {
  $getJSON(parameter, callback);
}
```

Comment: Well explained, I completely understand now. However, I already have a function to be executed to handle the returned data like this: $getJSON(url, function(data){...}); how do I make this to work in this situation?

Comment: @user1824996: Put a call to `callback(data);` inside that callback function.

Comment: I just came out the same conclusion after reading a post. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to execute the callback function when the ajax call has completed:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
   (function(x) {
       request(arg[x], function(n) {
          console.log(n);
       });
   })(i);
}

function request(argX, callback) {
     $.getJSON('/url/json/', callback); //reference callback function
}
```

Comment: Same answer as Guffa's. I am just not sure how to pass the "callback" parameter in $getJSON() when there is a function(data) to be executed already. See my comment below.

Comment: The `function(data)` is passed back, that would be exactly the same as `function(n)` in the above code.

Comment: I am not sure I understand here completely. what I am trying to say is, can I do $getJSON('/url/json/', function(data){...}, callback); ? I don't think this is right though.